# How to access help pages from SQL*Plus prompt?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Does [SQL*Plus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL*Plus) provide the help pages for its commands? Is there a way to access the help text from the SQLPlus prompt, like this text for [**STARTUP**](http://ss64.com/ora/startup.html)?

I tried

```
SQL> man startup
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "man startu..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> startup -help
SP2-0714: invalid combination of STARTUP options
SQL> startup --help
SP2-0714: invalid combination of STARTUP options
SQL>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SQL>HELP STARTUP
```

From the [`Oracle docs`](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch4.htm#sthref626):

> To access command-line help for SQL*Plus commands, type HELP or ? followed by the command name at the SQL command prompt.

Comment: Sure would be nice if the sqlplus banner showed this info.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for HELP in Oracle SQL Plus is

HELP topic  (Topic is an SQL PLUS command or HELP COMMANDS)